# A proper way to download files with Xamarin?

Tags: pdf, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

In my Xamarin app I am displaying PDF files with WebView using PDF.js on the server. I want to add a download feature to my app to allow my users to download PDF documents.

I want to have a download button that downloads the file the way Chrome downloads a file, with notification entry and progress and everything else, so that the user has the same experience as if they downloaded the file from the web.

How can I do that? I can download the file myself but it wont be easy for the user to find it.

Answer (score 3):

```
    byte[] bytes = new byte[0]; //your byte array

        using (StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(FilePath, true))

        {
           BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(streamWriter.BaseStream);
           binaryWriter.Write(bytes);
        }

//As my file is in the path as shown below
var AppName = "MyApp";
var RootPath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;

var AppPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(RootPath, AppName);

if (!Directory.Exists(AppPath))
Directory.CreateDirectory(AppPath);

var FileName = $@"{mydoc.title}.{mydoc.doc_extension}";
var FilePath = Path.Combine(AppPath, FileName);

//You can give the user the option to open the file as shown below:

    var openFile= await DisplayActionSheet("Success", "open", "ok", "You have downloaded this document.");
     switch (openFile)
       {
           case "open":
           {
              Device.OpenUri(new Uri(FilePath));
              break;
           }
           case "ok":
           {
              break;
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty broad and open ended...that said, I would just have a simple progress dialog that tracks the progress of the file download, and display a notification when it finishes the downloading showing he user where the file was actually downloaded, something like this may help you: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.androidhive.info/2012/04/android-downloading-file-by-showing-progress-bar/amp/